# Is there any good trick for server to handle more requests if I don't have to sent any data back?

Tags: javascript, tcp, network-programming, connection, udp

I want to handle a lot of (> 100k/sec) POST requests from javascript clients with some kind of service server. Not many of this data will be stored, but I have to process all of them so I cannot spend my whole server power for serving requests only. All the processing need to be done in the same server instance, otherwise I'll need to use database for synchronization between servers which will be slower by orders of magnitude.

However I don't need to send any data back to the clients, and they don't even expect them.
So far my plan was to create few proxy servers instances which will be able to buffer the request and send them to main server in bigger packs.

For example let's say that I need to handle 200k requests / sec and each server can handle 40k. I can split load between 5 of them. Then each one will be buffering requests and sending them back to main server in packs of 100. This will result in 2k requests / sec on the main server (however, each message will be 100 times bigger - which probably means around  100-200kB). I could even send them back to the server using UDP to decrease amount of needed resources (then I need only one socket on main server, right?).

I'm just thinking if there is no other way to speed up the things. Especially, when as I said I don't need to send anything back. I have full control over javascript clients also, but unlucky javascript is unable to send data using UDP which probably would be solution for me (I don't even care if 0.1% of data will be lost).

Any ideas?

---

Edit in response to answers given me so far.

The problem isn't with server being to slow at processing events from the queue or with putting events in the queue itself. In fact I plan to use disruptor pattern (http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/) which was proven to process up to 6 million requests per second.

The only problem which I potentially can have is need to have 100, 200 or 300k sockets open at the same time, which cannot be handled by any of the mainstream servers. I know some custom solutions are possible (http://www.metabrew.com/article/a-million-user-comet-application-with-mochiweb-part-3) but I'm wondering if there is no way to even better utilization of fact that I don't have to replay to clients.

(For example some way to embed part of the data in initial TCP packet and handle TCP packets as they would be UDP. Or some other kind of magic ;))

Answer (score 1):

Make a unique and fast (probably in C) function that get's all requests, from a very fast server (like nginx). The only job of this function is to store the requests in a very fast queue (like redis if you got enought ram).

In another process (or server), depop the queue and do the real work, processing request one by one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the clients, as you say, then your proxy server doesn't even need to be an HTTP server, because you can assume that all of the requests are valid.

You could implement it as a non-HTTP server that simply sends back a 200, reads the client request until it disconnects, and then queues the requests for processing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is an implementation of a [Message Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue).  You also will need something to hand off these requests to whatever queue you use ([RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) is quite good, there are many alternatives).

You'll also need something else running which can do whatever processing you actually want on the requests.  You haven't made that very clear, so I'm not too sure exactly what would be right for you.  Essentially the idea will be that incoming requests are dumped as quickly as simply as possible into the queue by your web server, and then the web server is free to go back to serving more requests.  When the system has some resources, it uses them to process the queue, but when it's busy the queue just keeps growing.

Not sure what platform you're on, but might want to look at something like [Lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/) for serving the POSTs.  You might (if same-domain restrictions don't shoot you down) get away with having Lighttpd running on a subdomain of your application (so post.myapp.com).  Failing that you could put a proper load balancer in front of your webservers altogether (so all requests go to www.myapp.com and the load balancer decides whether to forward them to the web server or the queue processor).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MongoDB for persisting your requests, it's **fire and forget** mechanism can help your servers to response faster.